# How can I display the total number of perfect and number matches in a mastermind type game

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, boolean

I need help with part of my mastermind game. I have a randomly generated 4 int code and the user has 10 tries to guess it right (each guess has its own array). the user can get a perfect match (right number in the right array value), or a number match (right number wrong array value). How can I make a code that does this? Reads the users answer and displays the amount of matches he currently has.

each guess has its own array:

```
int [] guess1 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
int [] guess2 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

//and so on until guess 10.

Then I replace each guess with the arr in the game board:

```
if (newGuess == 1)
{
arr[0] = guess[0];
arr[1] = guess[1];
arr[2] = guess[2];
arr[3] = guess[3];
}
else if (newGuess == 2)
{
arr1[0] = guess[0];
arr1[1] = guess[1];
arr1[2] = guess[2];
arr1[3] = guess[3];
}
```

//and so on until guess 10

I just don't know how I can make a code that reads the perfect and number matches and displays the TOTAL perfect and number matches after each guess. I know this may be vague but I'm very stuck right now and I can provide further explanation if needed. Thanks :)

```
class MainClass 
{
  static Random rng = new Random();
  const int LETTER_SUBTRACTION = 48;
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    bool gameDone = false;
```

main loop

```
while(gameDone == false)
    {
      for(int newGuess = 0; newGuess <= 10; newGuess++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(newGuess);
        Console.Clear();
        DrawBoard();
        if (newGuess == 1)
        {
          GetGuess(guess1);
          ReplaceBoard(guess1, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 2)
        {
          GetGuess(guess2);
          ReplaceBoard(guess2, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 3)
        {
          GetGuess(guess3);
          ReplaceBoard(guess3, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 4)
        {
          GetGuess(guess4);
          ReplaceBoard(guess4, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 5)
        {
          GetGuess(guess5);
          ReplaceBoard(guess5, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 6)
        {
          GetGuess(guess6);
          ReplaceBoard(guess6, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 7)
        {
          GetGuess(guess7);
          ReplaceBoard(guess7, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 8)
        {
          GetGuess(guess8);
          ReplaceBoard(guess8, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 9)
        {
          GetGuess(guess9);
          ReplaceBoard(guess9, newGuess, code);
        }
        else if (newGuess == 10)
        {
          GetGuess(guess10);
          ReplaceBoard(guess10, newGuess, code);
        }
      }
      CheckMatch();
    }
```

My random code

```
private static int[] GetRandomCode()
  {
    //Store the numbers that represent the 8 possible numbers
    int [] numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    //Store the randomly generated code
    int [] code = new int[4];

    //Store the data needed to swap two elements of the numbers array
    int swapIndex1;
    int swapIndex2;
    int tempNumber;

    //Swap two random numbers in the numbers array 1000 times!
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      //Genereate 2 random index values in the numbers array range
      swapIndex1 = rng.Next(0,numbers.Length);
      swapIndex2 = rng.Next(0,numbers.Length);

      //Swap the numbers at those index locations
      //(like we did back in the variables lesson a long time ago)
      tempNumber = numbers[swapIndex1];
      numbers[swapIndex1] = numbers[swapIndex2];
      numbers[swapIndex2] = tempNumber;
    }

    //Now just grab the first four elements of the numbers array as
    //our random code
    code[0] = numbers[0];
    code[1] = numbers[1];
    code[2] = numbers[2];
    code[3] = numbers[3];

    //Return the code for game play to begin
    return code;
  }
```

arrays

```
static int [] arr = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr1 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr2 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr3 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr4 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr5 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr6 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr7 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr8 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] arr9 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

  static int [] guess1 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess2 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess3 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess4 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess5 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess6 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess7 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess8 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess9 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
  static int [] guess10 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

My board

```
private static void DrawBoard()
  {
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("   ---Mastermind--");
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("                          PERFECTS     NUMBERS");
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("   {?}    {?}    {?}    {?}");
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    Console.WriteLine("______________________________________________");
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr9[0], arr9[1], arr9[2], arr9[3], arr9[4], arr9[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr8[0], arr8[1], arr8[2], arr8[3], arr8[4], arr8[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr7[0], arr7[1], arr7[2], arr7[3], arr7[4], arr7[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr6[0], arr6[1], arr6[2], arr6[3], arr6[4], arr6[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr5[0], arr5[1], arr5[2], arr5[3], arr5[4], arr5[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr4[0], arr4[1], arr4[2], arr4[3], arr4[4], arr4[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr3[0], arr3[1], arr3[2], arr3[3], arr3[4], arr3[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr2[0], arr2[1], arr2[2], arr2[3], arr2[4], arr2[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], arr1[3], arr1[4], arr1[5]);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------+-----------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}   |      {4}            {5} ", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
    Console.ResetColor();
  }
```

getting player guess

```
private static void GetGuess(int [] guess)
  {
    string userGuess;

    Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");
    userGuess = Console.ReadLine();


    guess[0] = userGuess [0] - LETTER_SUBTRACTION;
    guess[1] = userGuess [1] - LETTER_SUBTRACTION;
    guess[2] = userGuess [2] - LETTER_SUBTRACTION;
    guess[3] = userGuess [3] - LETTER_SUBTRACTION;
  }
```

replacing board with player guess

```
private static void ReplaceBoard(int [] guess, int newGuess, int [] code)
  {
    bool checkMatches = false;

    if (newGuess == 1)
    {
      arr[0] = guess[0];
      arr[1] = guess[1];
      arr[2] = guess[2];
      arr[3] = guess[3];
    } 
    else if (newGuess == 2)
    {
      arr1[0] = guess[0];
      arr1[1] = guess[1];
      arr1[2] = guess[2];
      arr1[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 3)
    {
      arr2[0] = guess[0];
      arr2[1] = guess[1];
      arr2[2] = guess[2];
      arr2[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 4)
    {
      arr3[0] = guess[0];
      arr3[1] = guess[1];
      arr3[2] = guess[2];
      arr3[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 5)
    {
      arr4[0] = guess[0];
      arr4[1] = guess[1];
      arr4[2] = guess[2];
      arr4[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 6)
    {
      arr5[0] = guess[0];
      arr5[1] = guess[1];
      arr5[2] = guess[2];
      arr5[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 7)
    {
      arr6[0] = guess[0];
      arr6[1] = guess[1];
      arr6[2] = guess[2];
      arr6[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 8)
    {
      arr7[0] = guess[0];
      arr7[1] = guess[1];
      arr7[2] = guess[2];
      arr7[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 9)
    {
      arr8[0] = guess[0];
      arr8[1] = guess[1];
      arr8[2] = guess[2];
      arr8[3] = guess[3];
    }
    else if (newGuess == 10)
    {
      arr9[0] = guess[0];
      arr9[1] = guess[1];
      arr9[2] = guess[2];
      arr9[3] = guess[3];
    }
  }
```

Check match (what you told me)

```
private static void CheckMatch()
  {
    int perfectGuesses = 0;
    int numberGuesses = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < guess1.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == guess1[i])
    {
        guess1[guess1.Length - 2]++;
    }
    else if (arr.Contains(guess1[i]))
    {
        guess1[guess1.Length - 1]++;
    }
}
    guess1[4] = perfectGuesses;
    guess1[5] = numberGuesses;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what your goal is, but here is a guess at what you want:

```
using System.Linq;

int [] guess1 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0};
for (int i = 0; i < guess1.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == guess1[i])
    {
        guess1[guess1.Length - 2]++;
    }
    else if (arr.Contains(guess1[i]))
    {
        guess1[guess1.Length - 1]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: for the line else if (arr.Contains(guess1[i])) I get an error saying No overload for method `Contains' takes `2' arguments. Do you know why I get that? Thanks

Comment: have you included System.Linq?

Comment: Just added it I forgot, but now I get an error for that line saying Unexpected symbol `System', expecting `('

Comment: The 'System.Linq;' is supposed to be at the very top of your code, I just put it there so you know it should be included, did you put it at the very top?

Comment: Yeah I just fixed it, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I have each guess in its own array. The last 2 values of int [] guess1 = new int []{0,0,0,0,0,0}; are for the matches, 2nd last is for perfect matches and last is for number matches. I need to change those arrays according to the users answer. Does this help to give more context of what I'm looking for? Thanks.

Comment: and each guess has its own perfect and number match values... if this helps further

Comment: I think I'm understanding your problem better, I edited my answer, see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: It still doesn't display. I think maybe the variables might be wrong? my random code is in an array     int [] code = new int[4];
with values code[0] code[1] code[2] code[3]. My game board values are stored in arrays static int [] arr = {0,0,0,0,0,0}; //all the way to arr9. Could this be why it's not working? What would I need to change?

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show the full code? I might be able to figure something out then.

Comment: Just did. Didn't want to before since it was pretty long. if it's easier we can move this to something like discord? If not that's completely fine I appreciate the help however I can get it. Hopefully my full code helps you out. Thanks for the support

Comment: It would indeed be much easier if we moved it to discord, if you want to dm me its Aether#6180      , I'm going to keep checking it to see if i can find any errors